# Java: Strategy for limiting scope of a variable

Tags: java

I just stumbled over an error and asking myself if there is a better way do do it.

First I had this code.

```
// read lines out of a file and do something with it in foo
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("bla.txt")); 
String line; 
while ((line = br.readLine ()) != null) 
{
  foo (line);
}
br.close ();
```

Then I changed it. Introduced a list instead of working in the read-loop.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("bla.txt")); 
List <String> lst = new ArrayList <String> ();
String line; 
while ((line = br.readLine ()) != null) 
{
  lst.add (line);
}
br.close ();
for (String s : lst)
{
  foo (line);   // !!!
}
```

Please ignore the fact that is is not a real optimization. The code is just a simplification for my question.

In using the collection I did a mistake. I did keep foo(line) instaed of foo(s).
Thats no compiler error but wrong for my algorithm.

Whats a good strategy for avoiding this problem if making it more modular (using functions etc.) is not apropriate?

I thougt about limit the scope of line by putting it into a block.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("bla.txt")); 
List <String> lst = new ArrayList <String> ();

{
  String line; 
  while ((line = br.readLine ()) != null) 
  {
    lst.add (line);
  }
  br.close ();
}

for (String s : lst)
{
  foo (line);   // error now
}
```

But I am not sure thats a common and good strategy. Any suggestions for that kind of problem? Thanks!

Comment: Your for each loop makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Changed to correct for-loop

Comment: It still makes no sense? Why would you not use `s` in it?

Comment: @MuratKaragöz that is part of the question, OP wants to avoid possible logical errors the compiler / IDE doesn't get. I think he wants this line to be either using `s` or getting highlighted as *not possible* or *won't compile*.

Comment: The block is the correct generic technical solution IMO (unless it makes sense to extract the code using the variable in a function), but you're right that it's not so common. Either make it a common practice in your code base since you seem to want to solve the problem in general, or write a comment that explains why you create a scope, or trust your (and your peers) development skills and your tests to catch such errors. I think it would be a real hassle to have to define a bloc around each new variable definition, so you have to think about how much it would actually help you

Comment: The question is confusing. Are you trying to hide the variable `line` so that it can't be accessed outside the `while` loop?

Comment: Are you asking how to avoid introducing runtime errors (as opposed to compile time errors) in your code in general, or specifically for the code you posted?

Comment: basically, you ran into a "semantic error". the compiler can only enforce grammar, and not the intent. so there's really no good way to "defend against yourself" other than using non-primitive objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution specific to your sample code : you can declare variables in a for loop's initialization statement which will only be accessible in the loop's body.

```
for (String line=br.readLine(); line != null ; line = br.readLine()) {
    //line is accessible
}
// line is undeclared
```

Every `while` loop can be converted to a `for` loop, but the resulting loop might often be confusing, so comment profusely.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is having a pure function [1]. In order to achieve that you should have two separate functions, one to read the content and another to process it. The second function should take a parameter as a list. Something like below :

```
List<String> readContent(){ 
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("bla.txt")); 
   List <String> lst = new ArrayList <String> ();

   {
     String line; 
     while ((line = br.readLine ()) != null) 
     {
       lst.add (line);
      }
    br.close ();
   }
   return lst;
}

void processContent(List<String> contentList){
 for (String s : contentList){
  foo (s);   // error now
 }
}
```

In your main method, you will call both the functions like following:

```
List<String> contents = readContent();
processContent(contents);
```

Furthermore, there should be a Unit Test for both of the function as well.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function

Answer (score 2):

This is just a suggestion and it only works when resources are used, but in your case, you could

1. get rid of the `br.close()` and
2. limit the scope where `line` is declared just by using a `try`-with-resource approach.

have a look at the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List <String> lst = new ArrayList <String> ();

    // specifically try the BufferedReader, it will get closed in every case
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bla.txt"))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            lst.add(line);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    lst.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s)); // Java 8 for-each
}
```

As adviced, I have ignored the fact that your question does not ask for a real optimization.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear if you want to access the line variable after list is populated, but if you don't, you can remove it completely.

```
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("bla.txt")));

for (String s : lst) {
  foo(line);   // error now
}
```